# Parallel steps in spring batch 1.1

Tags: parallel-processing, spring-batch

Hy,

Having to use spring batch 1.1, due to limitations to the machine where the process is going to run, I have some doubts about configuring parallel steps. In newer versions of spring batch you can do this with flow package in spring batch but this package does not exist in version 1.1.

1. How can I get distinct steps execute in its own thread in spring batch 1.1?(By default I understand that steps configured inside a job are sequential)

Thanks

Comment: Consider using concurrent jobs instead, each with one step

Comment: What machine constraints do you have that limit you to Spring Batch 1.1?

Comment: The machine has a jre 1.5, thats why. How to use concurrent jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best place to read when it comes to Spring batch parallel processing:

```
[http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html][1]

<job id="job1">
    <split id="split1" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="step4">
        <flow>
            <step id="step1" parent="s1" next="step2"/>
            <step id="step2" parent="s2"/>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="step3" parent="s3"/>
        </flow>
    </split>
    <step id="step4" parent="s4"/>
</job>

<beans:bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.spr...SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
```

The key moment in the fragment above is the taskExecutor definition for the multithreading. And the fact that the steps "step1,step2" are declared in a single flow, while step3 in another flow. This mean that step1 and step 2 will run sequentially to each other , but in parallel with step 3.

Comment: Thanks but as I said, Spring batch 1.1 doesnt come with flow classes so I cannot use it